# Lag when sending an http request using POCO C++ libraries

Tags: c++, http, poco-libraries

I have written a program making an http POST request to google-analytics using the following code:

```
    Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession session("www.google-analytics.com");
    Poco::Net::HTTPRequest req(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, "/collect",Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
    Poco::URI uri("");
    uri.addQueryParameter("v", "1");
    ////// more parameters of the uri //////
    req.setContentLength(uri.getRawQuery().length());
    session.sendRequest(req) << uri.getRawQuery();
```

A user of the program has reported a 20 seconds freeze of the program every time a request is made. I have not been able to replicate the problem on any other computer, nor understand where it could come from.
He uses an ethernet connection to a modem TP-Link 300Mbps Wireless N Gigabit ADSL2+Modem Router TD-W8970. When the modem is turned off, the lag does not occur (my code throws an exception when sendRequest fails).
Any help/suggestion on the problem would be much appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing this on the main thread?

Comment: I am yes. Well it's single-threaded to be more precise.